# vb6.0 Can someone give me a code for this

Tags: vb6

Is it possible to stack items in list view? I have two list views the first one contains the data from MS access and when i click on the list items the clicked item will be transferred to the second list view but when i click again on the same item is it possible that the item will add?.

Comment: can you mention anything which you have tried for this.

Comment: I'd say that Stack Overflow doesn't cater to "give me a code" questions when no effort is shown, but as usual, someone has gone ahead and answered anyways

Answer (score 2):

This example assumes two ListBox controls (`List1` and `List2`) are on your `Form1`

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Dim count As Integer

    Do Until count > 20  ' add items to List1
        Me.List1.AddItem (Format$(count))
        count = count + 1
    Loop

End Sub

Private Sub List1_Click()
    ' when List1 is clicked add the item from List1 to List2
    Me.List2.AddItem Me.List1.Text
End Sub
```